# When does the BluetoothGattCallback and onConnectionStateChange been called in Android for BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am study about Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, Bluetooth 4.0) for Android.

I have reference the document like the link: [Bluetooth Low Energy](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#notification).

It use `connectGatt()` method for connecting to the GATT server on the **`device-A`** like the following.

`mBluetoothGatt = device_A.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);`

And it has `onConnectionStateChange` , `onCharacteristicRead` ,etc in the `mGattCallback`.

**`The question is:`**

**1.  When does the `BluetoothGattCallback` has be called ?**

**2. Is the `onConnectionStateChange` in the `mBluetoothGatt` will return the message when the `device-A` has any change for all characteristic on the `device-A` ?? , or it only return the characteristic which the characteristic I have connect??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all after connection (you are connectiong as gatt-client to device as gatt-server) you should call Discovery device's services. After that device can send you `onCharacteristicChanged` in case of some changes happened. 
But there is a case when BLE device could be as gatt-client and should send `writeCharacteristic` to your `BluetoothGattServer`. In that case you should create gatt-server and receive calls.

Comment: Thanks , I have already get the battery from BLE device by using battery Service. Is that mean BluetoothGattServer on Android side ?

Comment: @Wun I guess no, you just read (as gatt-client) battery characterictic from BLE device (gatt-server). Gatt-server is those who provide services.

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko Can you help me out with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099824/ble-bluetoothgattcallback-gets-a-state-disconnected-when-device-is-still-on